# Two separate Gmail accounts

Tags: gmail, user-accounts

There are two separate users with separate Gmail accounts on this computer. However, now that my brother has signed up for Gmail, he is the only one who can sign into an account on the computer. It automatically comes up with his address and won't let me switch to mine. I am effectively locked out of my account.

Answer (score 2):

In the upper right corner where you see your brother's profile photo, click it. You should then get a menu with a "Sign out" option. Click it, then sign in as yourself.

To avoid this in the future, can also...

- Use different browser profiles

or

- Use different browsers

or

- Use different OS user accounts